# Incorrect result for the region of convergence of a simple integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex

**Bug persisting at least through version 11.3.0**

The standard Gaussian integral

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x^2], {x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

returns

```
ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[Pi]/Sqrt[a], Re[a] > 0]
```

But if we manually substitute `a = I`, which apparently lies outside the integral's region of convergence, we get that

```
Integrate[Exp[-I x^2], {x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

returns

```
 (1 - I) Sqrt[Pi/2]
```

contradicting the answer to the more general problem, which implies that this integral does not converge. More generally,

```
Assuming[Element[k, Reals], Integrate[Exp[I k x^2], {x,-Infinity,Infinity}]]
```

returns

```
(Sqrt[Pi/2] (1 + I Sign[k]))/Sqrt[Abs[k]]
```

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity) Wikipedia article explains why the latter answers are correct. Why is the first result giving too small of a region of convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram Tech Support has confirmed that this is a bug in Mathematica.

Answer (score -1):

The expression is in fact regular for a=0 i.e. Re[a]=0. Assume

```
L > 0
```

and compute

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x^2], {x,-L,L}]
```

obtaining the function

```
(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[a] L])/Sqrt[a]
```

which is regular in the point a=0, as Erf[x] ~ 2x/Sqrt[Pi] + O[x^3].

So as you correctly wrote for purely imaginary a, Re[a]=0 the integral
converges.

Comment: As $a \to 0$ the integral goes to $2L$, so it's regular for *finite* L, but the limit $L \to \infty$ required for the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ does not exist. The integral does not converge if $a = 0$. Anyway, it doesn't answer my question, which is why Mathematica is returning the wrong answer.